How to evaluate $\int_{-1} ^ 1 \frac{1}{(8 + x ^ 2)\sqrt{1 - x ^ 2}} dx$?
I encountered this integration question when completing the integration bee from CMIMC 2023.
Right now, I don't really have any idea as to how to approach the integral. Could anyone offer some hints?

Using $x = \sin t$ is a good first step.

Perhaps unsuitable for an integration bee, but contour integration would work

Thanks for the two ideas above!

$$I=\int_{-1}^1\frac{dx}{(8+x^2)\sqrt{1-x^2}}
=2\int_0^1\frac{dx}{(8+x^2)\sqrt{1-x^2}}.$$
Let $x=\sin t$, then, using $1+\tan^2t=\sec^2t$ and $d\tan t=\sec^2t\ dt$, we have
\begin{align}
I&=2\int_{0}^{\frac\pi2}\frac{dt}{8+\sin^2t}\\
&=2\int_{0}^{\frac\pi2}\frac{dt}{\cos^2t(8\sec^2t+\tan^2t)}\\
&=2\int_{0}^{\frac\pi2}\frac{d(\tan t)}{8+9\tan^2t}\\
&=2\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{du}{8+9u^2}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{6\sqrt2}.
\end{align}

@ Doug
Riemann Hypothesis is so big problem for me!

\begin{aligned}
& I=2 \int_0^1 \frac{1}{\left(8+\frac{1}{x^2}\right) \sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x^2}}} \frac{d x}{x^2} \quad \text { via } x \mapsto \frac{1}{x} \\
& =2 \int_1^{\infty} \frac{x}{\left(8 x^2+1\right) \sqrt{x^2-1}} d x \\
& =\int_1^{\infty} \frac{d x}{(8 x+1) \sqrt{x-1}} \quad  \text { via } x^2\mapsto x  \\
& =2 \int_1^{\infty} \frac{d(\sqrt{x-1})}{8 (\sqrt{x-1})^2+9} \\
& =\frac{1}{3 \sqrt{2}}\left[\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{8(x-1)}}{3}\right)\right]_1^{\infty} \\
& =\frac{\pi}{6 \sqrt{2}} \\
&
\end{aligned}
